# What is the best way to cancel running Completable (RX2)?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

What is the best way to cancel long running operation which starts from UI through RX2 Completable?

I have the follow code:

```
Completable completable = Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        final LongTaskManager ltm = new LongTaskManager();
        ltm.doLongTask();
        e.onComplete();
    }
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

Disposable disposable = completable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                //...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                //...
            }
        });
```

On leaving UI

```
disposable.dispose()
```

is called.

After dispose() I won't receive events in Observer (onComplete/onError), but long running task will continue to run.

Seems that "isInterrupted" flag should be added to LongTaskManager (like as in java.lang.Thread), it should be set on leaving UI and handled in LongTaskManager#doLongTask().

But I'm not sure that it is right way while using Rx, and would like to clarify this aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable`/`Completable` will send Thread Interrupt signal to the thread you are performing the subscription on, so stopping the operation depends on what `doLongTask()` exactly does, and if it does it on the Subscription thread or fork the work to some other Thread.

Besides that you can and should provide Cancellation/Disposable logic if your operation can be cancelled/stopped explicitly, this can be done using `Emitter.setCancellable()`/`setDisposable()`, see additional info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867995/3903847).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I got new information. But if to be honest I am still not sure what I should do =(

Seems that I should add setCancellable in order my code looks smt like this:
`final LongTask ltm = new LongTask();
e.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
     @Override
                    public void cancel() throws Exception {
                       ltm.interrupt();
                   }
               });
             ltm.doLongTask();
            e.onComplete();`

<br/>interrupt() method will correctly stop my task (releasing resources and etc)

<br/>Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly, there is no magic here, you should provide the logic to stop the long running task, and Observable mechanism will make sure to execute this logic.

Comment: Sounds great :)
@yosriz ,may be you know a link where there is info about differences in setDisposable and setCancelable? Unfortunately i coundn't find. If I set both `(e.setCancellable(new Cancellable() ....);  e.setDisposable(new Disposable() ...)` then both events happens on `disposable.dispose();` So i don't see difference in theirs behavior

Comment: They're not called exactly both, the later causing the first to dispose and execute its logic , so you actually apply your cancellation logic immediately when you subscribe, see documentation.