# How to implement an interrupted thread in rxjava?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java2

I have the following code that I want to turn Reactive:

```
class ReadThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String result = doBlockingIO();
                listener.onReceivedData(result);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if I want to stop I/O operation I call

```
readThread.interrupt();
```

My initial rxjava2 implementation is as per bellow:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {doBlockingIO();}))
            .repeat()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new ResourceSubscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String data) {
                    onReceivedData(data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    onErrorOccurred(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }));
```

As this is an Android application, on my `onStop()` Activity callback I call `dispose()` on the composite disposable above.

Running the above rxjava2 code on certain devices has some weird side effects, as when I stop IO Activity and move to another Activity that is also using similar composite disposable and IO operations, some operations seem to freeze. Also by looking at some logs I can tell that rxjava2 Thread running `doBlockingIO` completes after I leave and come back to the IO Activity:

```
07-21 19:18:17.420 5774-434/com.mobile.installation E/IOActivity: doBlockingIO() -> PRE RxCachedThreadScheduler-5 --->> LEFT ACTIVITY
07-21 19:18:30.134 5774-565/com.mobile.installation E/IOActivity: doBlockingIO() -> PRE RxCachedThreadScheduler-6 --->> RE-ENTERED ACTIVITY
07-21 19:18:30.847 5774-434/com.mobile.installation E/IOActivity: doBlockingIO() -> POST RxCachedThreadScheduler-5
```

Any idea on how to implement the typical java IO interrupt scenario properly with rxjava2?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855841/do-i-need-to-free-release-observable-object-after-i-use-it/44867995#44867995

Comment: Thanks @LordRaydenMK, I was doing what was indicated in the stackoverflow post above, i.e. I was disposing the composite disposable when no longer needed. My IO operation involves continually reading from an OS serial port. I realised two things, (1) I do need the ``repeat()`` operator as the source will keep producing characters and (2) using ``Schedulers.io()`` somehow blocked rx Thread, so I reverted to ``Schedulers.newThread()`` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @mtsahakis could you clarify what you mean by "some operations seem to freeze" ? Are you saying the UI thread freezes or blockingIO takes too long?

Comment: The problem I was facing was once I pressed back and called dispose(). As indicated on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855841/do-i-need-to-free-release-observable-object-after-i-use-it/44867995#44867995 the code was getting an interrupt and throwing an IO Exception, which is fine. But when I entered another activity, where I was again using ``Schedulers.io()``, the I/O operation (fetch data from SQLite, nothing to do with ``doBlockingIO()`` method) froze. Once I moved to ``Schedulers.newThread`` as indicated on my previous comment, the app is behaving fine.